# Designing functions/programs according to automaton

Tags: automata

Suppose I have two function that always return 1 + 1:

```
def one_plus_one():
    return 1 + 1
```

and Python's `eval(x)` that accepts any string as input and produce any possible output as the current computer can execute.

So, can I say that the `one_plus_one` function is a Finite Automata (or Finite State Machine) and Python's `eval()` is a Turing machine?

I'm thinking of writing an app and as I add more features to the apps, the more data my app must take as input. At some point, I start thinking what's the ramification to all the data that I want my app to take? Will it approach an language interpreter and in the end, my app is just a fancy interpreter? That's when this reminds me of the Automata Theory lectures I took before.

Is my thinking the correct application of Automata Theory?

Comment: Is this a serious question ? In what way would this be an FSM ? Which states ? Which transitions ? Why computing $1+1$ rather than plugging $2$ ?? There is not even an input !? The `eval` function has nothing in common with a TM !!

Comment: @YvesDaoust the 1+1 function can be think of as a FM with empty input, initial state = 0, output the only state that is 2; so, `one_plus_one` only has a finite states of `0` and `2` and `1+1` is the transition function. On the other hand, `eval` is a Python implementation, thus it is Turing complete.

Comment: I see. The answer is *no*. You are not thinking the correct application of Automata Theory. Not even close to. You are randomly aggregating some concepts.